Can Floor and Ceiling Be Ignored to Simplify $T(n) = 3T(⌊n/5⌋) + 3T(⌈n/5⌉) + 200n \lg n$ for Master Theorem?
I'm working on a problem set where I need to apply the Master Theorem to several recurrences. One of them is:
$$T(n) = 3T(⌊n/5⌋) + 3T(⌈n/5⌉) + 200n \lg n$$
The question asks to use the Master Theorem and give the solution using big-$Θ$ notation, or explain why it doesn't apply.
Section 1.3 in these notes (CS 161 Lecture 3) contains the Master Theorem.
In our recent lecture, we discussed a recurrence:
$$T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/4) + n$$
which does not match the form for recurrence, so the Master Theorem does not apply.
Given this, I'm unsure whether the Master Theorem can be applied here. Can the floor and ceiling functions be ignored, allowing me to approximate the recurrence as:
$$T(n) ≈ 6T(n/5) + 200n \lg n$$
to fit the Master Theorem's standard form?
Any insights or guidance on whether the Master Theorem is applicable here would be greatly appreciated!

Maybe write $n$ in base 5.

Image from CLRS textbook chapter 4
This is a screenshot from the intro to algorithms textbook about how the T(n) function is formed. Hopefuly this helps

Welcome to stackexchange. I'm glad you want to help, but link only answers are not acceptable on this site. If you want to write an answer that explicitly addresses the OP's question please do. You can cite this source with a link.
